# Objective c - Waiting the excution for a bool value set to true

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

i want to wait the method execution untill bool value is set true.

```
-(void)method1
{
    while (!self.setFlag)
    {

    }

    NSLog(@"1");
}
```

If i wrote in while loop ,the present UI is not responding.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do before setting the variable?

Comment: You want a semaphore - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Answer (score 0):

Hangs because you are probably running this on the main thread.

However you rather want to change the design to evoke the method when the bool is set to YES. Question is, what event does change the bool? If the BOOL is an ivar of your class then you could write your own setter that also covers calling your method.
If the BOOL belongs to a different class or framework, inherit or create a wrapper class that deals with that problem.

What BOOL you what to watch?